# Enrich the information of one field with another table field

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is it possible in acces, in a table, in edit mode, normal in grid mode, in a combo box field, to make this combo box show some values, but to select them, save others?

I need this because, in Declarado, Comprobado and Documentos tables, I want a composite text to appear between a foreign key and a field in the foreign table, and that the value that is saved when selected is obviously the value of the foreign key selected.

I explain it in pictures

[image]

As you can see in the first image, I have four tables, Expedientes, Declarado, Comprobado and Documentos.

[image]

But this I just want to appear in the drop-down, I think this forces me to use a form and program it with Vb, right?

I can upload the BD if you need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a form whose **Record Source** is the `Comprobado` table (whose records you are currently editing by opening the table in Grid View).

Then, insert a Combobox on the form and set the **Control Source** of the combobox to the `Num_Expediente` field, and the **Row Source** to a query containing both the `Num_Expediente` field and `Nombre_OT` field, e.g.:

```
select t.Num_Expediente, t.Nombre_OT from Expedientes t order by t.Num_Expediente
```

Set the **Column Count** property to 2 and size the columns appropriately for your data using the **Column Widths** property. Set the **Bound Column** property to column 1, so that the `Num_Expediente` is populated with the correct data.